# What is the problem with the propTypes object, string and array which makes eslint to have this rule: react/forbid-prop-types?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've been programming on React for about a year and I always see this `react/forbid-prop-types` coming, so I have this rule out: `// eslint-disable-next-line react/forbid-prop-types`, like:

```
SigninSubmitButton.propTypes = {
  signInAsync: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  disabledProp: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.bool, PropTypes.number])
    .isRequired,
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/forbid-prop-types
  style: PropTypes.array,
};
```

What is the problem with those types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> By default this rule prevents vague prop types with more specific
>   alternatives available (any, array, object)

So either type your array as its real type or turn off the rule

> This rule is a formatting/documenting preference and not following it
>   won't negatively affect the quality of your code. This rule encourages
>   prop types that more specifically document their usage.

https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/forbid-prop-types.md